# How to parse it using jquery ajax form values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, parsing

How to parse form values and want to validate 15 object has values are not it is exist or not. I have tried it using jQuery.parseJSON() but it is not working.

```
    [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object,Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object…]
[0 … 99]
0: Object
1: Object
name: "form_token"
value: "ZEQq-70EBd5vy82OECyLjun4evRCnw6cdlRepv8mhbY"
__proto__: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
name: "video[field_phone]"
value: ""
__proto__: Object
5: Object
name: "video[field_phone_ext]"
value: ""
__proto__: Object
6: Object
7: Object
8: Object
9: Object
10: Object
11: Object
12: Object
13: Object
14: Object
15: Object
name: "files[video_field_photo]"
value: ""
__proto__: Object
```

thanks

Comment: It is already a json array

Comment: Then how to parse it and get the object 15 value

Comment: Access it using index `14`, worked?

Comment: Can you please write a code . That will help me thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Values` is your json array.
Then you can access the 15th item of your object and check for its value using

```
Values[14].value
```